# <Lightning:select> isnt working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

***Problem facing: If I change a value in Lightning select.for example Iam changing particularly one row value. But automatically other row values also changing***

Image 1 : Iam changing a lightning select value in one row .
[image]

Image 2:I have changed  first row value has payment master, Automatically It effects remaining row value also

[image]

```
 <aura:component controller="ActionController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="theId" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="wrplst" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="option" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<p>
    <b>Creating Action Criteria </b>
</p>
<h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
    <I> Action Criteria</I>
</h3>
<table >
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
        <th class="head">
            <I>Action</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Object Name</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Component</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
        </th>
        <th class="head">
            <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
        <tr>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <button type="button" onclick="{!c.RemoveClick}">remove</button>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>

                        <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.selectedValue}" onchange="{!c.dosomething}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                                <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:select>

                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <P>
                    <lightning:select name="select" label=" ">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </P>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" ">
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                        <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                        <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                        <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                        <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " >
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                        <option value="*">*</option>
                        <option value="*/">*/</option>
                        <option value="/">/</option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <ui:inputText value="{!a.specialOperatorValue}"/>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="cell" >
                <p>
                    <ui:inputText value="{!a.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</table>
<lightning:button label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow}" />
```

**js:**

```
  ({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.pageLoad(component);
    helper.optionval(component);
},
doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('iam calling :::');
    var x = component.find("x").get("v.value");
    alert('x value ::::' + x);
},
RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {

},
AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

    var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);

    var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
    addAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson1
    });
    addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
        var state = res.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.wrplst", res.getReturnValue());
        } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
            alert('error');
        } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
            alert('incompltete');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
},
dosomething: function(component, event, helper) {
    var x = component.get("v.selectedValue");
    alert(x);
}
```

### })

helper  :

({

```
        pageLoad: function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.pageLoading");
    var self = this;
    var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
    action.setParams({
        "id": Idx
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(g) {
        var state = g.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
            self.Method2(component);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
optionval: function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts = [{
            value: "",
            label: "None"
        },
        {
            value: "Pay_Element_Master__c",
            label: "Pay Element"
        },
        {
            value: "CTC_Master__c",
            label: "CTC Master"
        }
    ];
    component.set("v.options", opts);
},
Method2: function(component, event, helper) {
    var comp = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
    var Id1 = component.get("v.theId");
    var compAction = component.get("c.getComponent");
    compAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson,
        "id": Id1,
    });
    compAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
        var state = re.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(compAction);
}
```

})

Comment: I just threw your code into my org and it worked fine..

Comment: I think your code will work....I think you are setting same  `aura:Id`  for other tags in your markup cmp.verify it

Comment: Hi I updated the code please check it.                                                                      I have tried like this also :  var xval= component.find("obId").get("v.value");  but its shows error..I have copied and tried same code its working for me..but here itsnt working...

Comment: I am confused, your first line says "in Lightning select its working." yet your title says it is not. You last comment says it shows error but then you say you have tried same code and its working for you. Then say here its not working. How can it be working yet not, and same code is but isn't????

Comment: Hi Eric..please check it now..I have updated it...I have tried same code in same org..I created component and used same code means only lightning select option ...I got result..but here it shows error...please check the  code..I hope know its clear!!

Comment: As others have said, **that select in isolation works without issue**. I just verified it on my end as well. If you cannot find another element with the id obId in your markup, Try commenting out all of your component elements except that one and see if it works (it should). then start adding back in until it breaks, then you will know what caused it.

Comment: The issue here is the `selectedValue` attribute you are binding with all the select elements, for this you should use a child component for the fields between `aura:iteration`.

Comment: How to do that? can you please tell me one scenario @itzmukeshy7

Comment: How to use a  child component can you please explain me a bit

Comment: Child and parent both are same in the way of development, We add child component in the parent like `<c:childComponentName attribute1="value1" ... />`

Comment: But how I use in this scenario.I didnt get..I confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

In the main component replace the `aura:iteration` with child component like:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a" indexVar="i">
  <c:formFields options="{!v.options}" selectedValue="" />
</aura:iteration>
```

**formFields.cmp** Child Component

*NOTE:* I have added only select field add more as per the need.

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute required="true" name="options" type="String[]"/>
  <aura:attribute required="true" name="selectedValue" type="String"/>

  <tr>
    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
            <!--  @todo implement RemoveClick in formFieldsController.js -->   
            <button type="button" onclick="{!c.removeClick}">remove</button>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cell" >
        <p>
            <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " value="{!v.selectedValue}" onchange="{!c.selectChanged}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                    <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select> 
        </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</aura:component>
```

**formFieldsController.js**

```
({

  selectChanged: function(component, event, helper){
    var x = component.get("v.selectedValue");
    alert(x);
  },
  removeClick: function(component, event, helper){
    /**
     * @todo Implement functionality here.
     */
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see what the problem is here. Here is explanation of why it is behaving so->

As you are binding **v.options** aura attribute with lightning:select, as soon as you add new row, the lightning select of other row is also bound to the same **v.options** attribute.

Now if you change the select from UI in one of the data row, it will change the **v.options** by putting selected true in the selected option. As same **v.options** is connected by the second i.e. 'in your case all rows', that changed value in it will be reflected to all data rows.

This is why when you change select in one rows, others also get changed to the same value.

**Soluton - >**

Better solution would be to associate javascript attributes named options and selectedValue with the wrapper of each row. This will not hard bind options of each row with the **v.options** attribute. Something like tihs->

1. Change this line of code in your component's cmp file->

TO

```
<lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " aura:id="mySelect" value="{!v.wrplst.selectedValue}" onchange="{!c.dosomething}">
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst.options}" var="item">
    <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

2. Change this line of code in your controller file's add row function - >

   component.set("v.wrplst", res.getReturnValue());

TO

```
//I assume this returns a row of wrapper
var row = res.getReturnValue();

// this line will create copy of options and selectedvalue for each row
row['options'] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(comopnent.get('v.options')));
row['selectedValue'] = //what ever you want to select by default on first load of the screen from options.

// now set it in wrplist
var wrapperList = component.get('v.wrplst');
wrapperList.push(row);
component.set('v.wrplst',wrapperList);
```

3. Change this line in your pageLoad helper method ->

   component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));

TO

```
//I assume that this response g is returning a list of wrappers
var rowList = JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue());
rowList = rowList.map(function(row){
 row['options'] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(comopnent.get('v.options')));
 row['selectedValue'] = //what ever you want to select by default on first load of the screen from options.
 return row;
});
component.set('v.wrplst',rowList);
```

You may need some code changes in a way how to handle the select change, but this much will solve your query.
You can email me on sawneyaman3@gmail.com for any query related to lightning development.